# If $f$ continuous differentiable and $f'(r) < 1,$ then $x'=f(x/t)$ has no other solution tangent at zero to $\phi(t)=rt$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous differentiable function such that $f(r)=r,$ for some $r.$ Then how to show that

> If $f'(r) < 1,$  then the problem 
>   $$x'=f(x/t)$$ has no other solution tangent at zero to $\phi(t)=rt, t>0$.

Tangent here means

$$\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}\frac{\psi(t)-\phi(t)}{t}=0$$

I could only prove that $\psi(0^+)=0,$ and $\psi'(0^+)=r.$ The problem was to use the fact that $f'(r) < 1.$

Comment: Is $x'$ supposed to mean $x'(t)$?

Comment: The wording is rather strange; $x$ should be proven to be tangent to $\phi$ at $0$?

Comment: Yeah, @PeterT.off!

Comment: @math What is $ψ$?

Comment: If $f'(r)<1$ then $f$ is greater than $r$ in $r-\epsilon$ and smaller than $r$ in $r+\epsilon$

Comment: Well my approach was supposing that there was a solution $\psi$ tangent to $\psi$ then I would infer that this solution was equal to $\phi$.

Comment: I added a long-ish title, but more informative I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Peter Tamaroff gave a very good [hint in comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123115/if-f-continuous-differentiable-and-fr-1-then-x-fx-t-has-no-other#comment284637_123115). Here is what comes out of it.

Suppose that $x$ is a solution tangent to $rt$ and not equal to it. Since solution curves do not cross, either (i) $x(t)>rt$ for all $t>0$, or (ii) $x(t)<rt$ for all $t>0$. I will consider (i), the other case being similar.

By assumption, $x/t\to r$ as $t\searrow 0$. From $$f(x/t)=r+f'(r)(x/t-r)+o(x/t-r)$$ and $f'(r)<1$ we obtain
$$t(x/t)'=f(x/t)-x/t = (f'(r)-1)(x/t-r)+o(x/t-r)$$
which is *negative* for small $t$. This means that $x/t$ increases as $t\searrow 0$, contradicting $x/t\to r$.

Comment: I did not quite understand your solution. Do you suppose x a rt solution? This diagonal arrow means what?