# Solutions of a homogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

Consider a homogeneous differential equation $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = f\left(\dfrac{x}{t}\right)$, where $f(k)=k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that

1. If $f'(k) < 1$ then there is no solution tangent to $x(t) = kt$ at the origin except the obvious one $x(t)=kt$.
2. If $f'(k) > 1$ then there is an infinite number of such solutions.

The author gives a hint:

> Two functions $y(t)$ and $x(t)$ defined for $t > 0$ are said to be tangent
>   at $0$ if $\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \dfrac{y(t) - x(t)}{t} = 0$

I found some hints for 1. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123115/if-f-continuous-differentiable-and-fr-1-then-x-fx-t-has-no-other), but the answer given is not clear to me and the author's hint is not used, so I'm still stuck on the problem. For 2. I have no idea.

Comment: The link you provided specifies a function satisfying $f(r)=r$ for some $r\in\mathbb{R}$ whereas your question is about the identity function $f(k)=k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{R}$. Did you intend to say for some $k\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Yes, $f(k) = k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$. I have already edited the post.